# Copy a folder to Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I m running a jar application that uses some resources folder that needs to be in the same path as the jar:

here is an example of my folder how it uses to be :

```
    $ ls
__files  mappings  wiremock-standalone-2.24.0.jar
```

I'm able to push the jar file using

```
cf push wiremock-standalone-2.24.0.jar
```

But not able to push the two folders mappings and __files to pcf.

When I do :

```
cf push wiremock/__files
```

Ittries to create an app named wiremock/__files:

```
    Getting app info...
Creating app with these attributes...
+ name:       wiremock/__files
  path:       /tmp/build/2985dd2f
```

What is the command line I should use ?

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is add all missing files to your JAR package:

```
cp wiremock-standalone-2.24.0.jar wiremock-standalone-2.24.0-fat.jar
jar uf wiremock-standalone-2.24.0-fat.jar ./lib
```

Than your command will be exactly the same all you have to do is point to the new resources inside the Java app.

Answer (score 1):

`cf push` is used to deploy an application to a container. Anything that is deployed with `cf push` is expected to be an executable app. Even if you were able to `cf push wiremock/__files` successfully, the files would end up in a different container and inaccessible from the container created for `cf push wiremock-standalone-2.24.0.jar`.

It sounds like you need the jar file, `__files`, and `mappings` to all be in the same container. To make this happen, you'll need to bundle them all into an archive and `cf push` them together.

Comment: Archive them into a new jar ? in this case how PCF knows that it should run the app .jar inside the new archive ?

Comment: When pushing a .jar file to CF, the CLI unpacks the jar (first level only) and pushes the individual files contained therein. So you could unpack `wiremock-standalone-2.24.0.jar` yourself to a temp dir, add `__files` and `mappings` to that temp dir, then give the directory location to `cf push -p`. That will cause `cf` to push everything in the temp dir.

Comment: The Java buildpack is responsible for detecting that a Java app has been deployed and setting the container up to run it. In this case, it will need a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` (from the unpacked jar file) to name the main class to run. See https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-java_main.md.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Alex Rashkov, I added the files to the jar and that worked perfectly.

My problem was exactly the same as in the original question, I want to deploy wiremock to PCF with pre-configured mappings, so I did the following:

- Started the wiremock server locally and defined the required mappings via the REST api (`/__admin/mappings/import` or `/__admin/mappings/new`)
- Saved the mappings (`__admin/mappings/save`)
- Now all the mappings will appear as files in the mappings directory
- Add the mappings directory to the jar file (`jar -uf wiremock-standalone-2.24.0.jar mappings`).  I just updated the downloaded jar file directly, but I can see where you might want to update a copy as suggested above.
- push the updated jar file to PCF (java_buildpack).  The wiremock server running in PCF will see the mappings in the mappings folder and have those predefined.

Thanks @Alex Rashkov for the tip!